# org-mode: counter for items, visible in export

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I'm writing a document in org-mode. Is it possible to use a counter for exercises that are spread across the document instead of numbering them myself? I am exporting this to HTML and PDF (via LaTeX). Example:

```
* First chapter
Blabla.

Exercise 1.

* Second chapter.

Blabla

Exercise 2.

* Third chapter.

Exercise 3.

Exercise 4.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this using dynamic blocks in org-mode.

In my init.el I defined the following:

```
(setf exercise-counter 0)
(defun org-dblock-write:reset-exercise-counter (params)
  (setf exercise-counter 0))
(defun org-dblock-write:exercise (params)
  (incf exercise-counter)
  (insert (concat "Exercise " (int-to-string exercise-counter) ".")))
```

At the top of my document I reset the counter:

```
#+BEGIN: reset-counter

#+END
```

Spread across the document I can now put this:

```
#+BEGIN: exercise
#+END
Blablabla.

#+BEGIN: exercise
#+END
Blablabla.
```

After calling `org-update-all-dblocks` the right numbers will be inserted.

[image: Text before]

[image: After]

Open for suggestions if anything can be improved.

How do I call `org-update-all-dblocks` automatically when exporting?
**ANSWER**: like this: `(add-hook 'org-export-first-hook 'org-update-all-dblocks)`